# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.getRequiredTestInstances()Lorg/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestInstances

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

I have some problem with junit5. I'm utilizing spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE. when i want to run empty test method i have been got this exception.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.getRequiredTestInstances()Lorg/junit/jupiter/api/extension/TestInstances
```

i'm sharing my code and i hope to you can help me.
**pom.xml**

```
    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Spring libs ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Cache libs ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Monitoring ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Database ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
            <version>${org.redisson}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Logging ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Security ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>0.10.6</version>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>0.10.6</version>-->
        <!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>0.10.6</version>-->
        <!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Rest and Soap client libs ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
            <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-annotation-error-decoder</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netflix.feign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>8.18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Dependencies which are not in java 11 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Other libs ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Apache Common libs ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ MapStruct ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Test ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Vault ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Swagger ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

**OperationServiceTest.java**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class OperationServiceTest {


    @Mock
    private UserService userService;

    @Mock
    private OperationRepository operationRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private OperationServiceImpl operationService;


    @Test
    void whenFillOperation() {

    }

}
```

when i remove the @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) annotation then class has been run success. Pls help me or pls share me example junit5 test with spring boot version 2.1.6

Comment: There’s a version mismatch somewhere. Spring Boot 2.1.6 is very old. Have you tried a more recent version?

Comment: Did you try adding `@ContextConfiguration` annotation containing the classes used in test?